# Should I use addslashes function when I using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, code-injection

I heard that PDO defends Injection Attack automatically.
So, I can make a query without ' mark.

Then, should I use addslashes function when I using PDO?

I means...

```
<?php
    $s = $d->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `no`=:n");
    $s->bindParam(":n", $data);
    $data = $_GET["param"];
    $s->execute();
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    $s = $d->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `no`=:n");
    $s->bindParam(":n", $data);
    $data = addslashes($_GET["param"]);
    $s->execute();
?>
```

Comment: *Never* use addslashes for sanitizing purposes.

Comment: **No**. *no*. No. *nyet*. **Nien.**

Comment: Thank you for answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't have to use it. When you're using prepared statements like `bindParam` the DB engine automatically do it for you.